# Calculate mean for each row across a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mean

I want to calculate the mean of each row in the 'value' column across a list of dataframes.

The output I want is a dataframe with the 'sample' name and its associated mean 'value' for each row across the whole list.

Below is some example data:

```
list <- list()

dataframe1 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                         gr = c("1","1","2","5","4","5","5","3","2","2","2","4","3","1","1","3","2","1","2","5","5","5","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","2","2","5","3","3","5"),
                         value = c("14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500"))

list[[1]] <- dataframe1

dataframe2 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
           gr = c("5","4","3","5","4","5","5","3","2","2","2","2","3","1","1","3","2","1","2","5","5","5","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","2","4","4","4","4","4"),
           value = c("12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000"))
list[[2]] <- dataframe2

dataframe3 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                         gr = c("5","3","3","5","5","5","5","3","5","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
                         value = c("20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915"))

list[[3]] <- dataframe3

dataframe4 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                         gr = c("2","2","2","3","4","5","5","3","2","2","2","4","5","1","1","3","2","1","2","5","5","5","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","2","2","5","3","3","5"),
                         value = c("18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500"))

list[[4]] <- dataframe4
```

Many thanks.
Cheers.
Deon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `base` functions, you could extract all the `value` columns into a matrix and use row means:

```
rowMeans(sapply(list, "[[", "value"))
```

For you sample data, you'd need to also convert to numeric (as below), but I'm hoping your real data has numbers not factors.

```
rowMeans(sapply(lapply(list, "[[", "value"), function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

This just gives the values (and assumes the rows are in the right order). You can add the sample names with `cbind`, e.g., `cbind(list[[1]][["sample"]], rowMeans(...))`.

Answer (score 2):

We can bind the `list` elements to a single data.frame, create a group of `row_number()` and use that to get the `mean` of 'value'

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list, .id = 'id') %>% 
          mutate(value = as.numeric(value))  %>%
          group_by(id) %>% 
          group_by(grp = row_number(), sample) %>%
          summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```